# How to get just the day from ISO string javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an ISO date coming back from a server and before I send it to the frontend I want to convert the ISO date to something like this

```
2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z
```

```
time: {
          day: 'Tue',
          hour: '11:54 AM',
          date: 'May 5, 2019'
        }
```

I dont want to use a bunch of regex unless I have to, I was hoping I could achieve this with just functions like .toDateString() etc... is there a toDateDayString or something like that?

Here is the snippet of the actual function sending the info back to my frontent.

Id like to be able to to this inline from a promise in .then()

```
allMessages = [] 

await subClient.conversations.services(convoServiceSid)
           .conversations(convo)
           .messages
           .list({limit: 20})
           .then(messages => messages.forEach(m =>
 allMessages.push({"messagesId": m.conversationSid, "time": m.dateCreated.toDateString() }) ));
//m.dateCreated is always going to be an ISO string, I want to make an object with day, hour, date if possible

res.json(allMessages)
```

Comment: Always look for the documentation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date everything is well explained with examples

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you didnt know this existed

Comment: Then you are lucky! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API for JavaScript built-in api into a browser, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference for js grammar and capabilities. This is the main always up to date resources.

Comment: This is great Im bout to lose my mind Im so happy

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this:

```js
const date = new Date('2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z');
const format = {
   day: date.getDay(),
   hour: `${date.getHours()} ${date.getMinutes()}`,
   date: `${date.getMonth()} ${date.getFullYear()}`
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) method

```js
function get_time(iso_date_str) {
  const [day, month_date, year, hour] = (
    new Date(iso_date_str).toLocaleDateString('en', {
      weekday: 'short',
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      month: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
      year: 'numeric',
    })
    .split(/,\s?/)
  );
  return {
    day,
    hour,
    date: month_date + ', ' + year
  };
}

console.log(get_time('2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z'));
```